# What is the idiomatic way in Rust to represent collections of items of different types?

Tags: collections, rust

In dynamic languages, like Clojure, it is easy to express collections with different types:

```clj
{:key1 "foo", :key2 [34 "bar" 4.5], "key3" {:key4 "foobar"}}
```

In Rust, I have seen the use of enums:

```
pub enum Value {
    Null,
    Bool(bool),
    Number(f64),
    String(String),
    ...
}
```

But different programmers will choose different enums to represent the same encapsulated type. There is also the [`Any` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html) but it is experimental.

What is the idiomatic way in Rust to represent collections of items of different types? Some examples and/or links to implementations would be very nice.

Comment: Note that Rust likes types very much!

Comment: `Any` is not experimental…

Comment: Only the [`get_type_id`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html#tymethod.get_type_id) method is experimental. But the trait is generally to be avoided any ways. Just use an `enum`.

Comment: Are these 2 implementations (traits and enums) the idiomatic choices in Rust? Do you have links to examples of Any used with collections in Rust?